# pygame windows resize without changing anything in content

Tags: python-2.7, resize, pygame, resolution

I am wondering if I can change window size and scale everything inside about 50 %. I would love to keep all the logic behind the program still relevant (for example pygame would register click on 1000 px, so after change at 500 px) I'm don't think there is an easy answer..

Comment: if you change window size then will have to recalculate buttons sizes and use this new sizes to check mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different ways you could go about this. If you want to pick a screen size and have it stay the same until you decide to change it on the backend, you can go to each call of `pygame.blit(foo)` or `pygame.draw.shape(foobar)` and scale up the dimensions of foo and foobar by 50%. That's the simple way, but it has some drawbacks. For example, if you ever want to change the screen size again, you'll have to do it over again. Certainly not ideal.

If you want the screen to be re-sizable by the user, or if you want to offer yourself greater flexibility in choosing your own screen size, you have to have some formulas to determine where to draw something based on screen size. For example, let's say you're doing a chess game. You could have something like this:

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
TILE_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 8
```

Then your drawBoard function could look like:

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ....
        #Color = black or white depending on which tile we're drawing
        pygame.draw.rect(mainWindow, color, (i * SCREEN_WIDTH, J * SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))
```

Now, if you want a larger screen, your tiles will scale up with it. Or, to make it a little more complicated, let's say you want a buffer between the chessboard and the window edge. Then you could do

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
BUFFER = 20
TILE_WIDTH = (SCREEN_WIDTH - BUFFER * 2) / 8
```

And your drawBoard function could look like:

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ....
        #Color = black or white depending on which tile we're drawing
        pygame.draw.rect(mainWindow, color, (BUFFER + i * SCREEN_WIDTH, BUFFER + J * SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))
```

This way will be harder short-term, but totally worth it in the long run. You'll have to also factor in whether you want *everything* to resize, or if there's a min/max size, and a couple of other thoughts, but I'm sure you can figure that out.